# Filtering words that have letters in the all of the same positions

Tags: javascript

This is for a Wordle solving challenge I'm trying to use to improve my string algo skills, but I'm stuck on how I can make this work for ALL characters where the indexes will match.

Lets say we have an array of words.

```js
['ducks', 'treks', 'tests', 'tease']
```

We know that the **1st letter** is a **T**, and the **2nd letter** is an **E**, so what we should get back is `['tests', 'tease']`.

This is using Vue, so [here's a reproduction of the component](https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-bird-octxr?file=/src/App.vue). Below is the method alone.

```js
fetchPotentialWords() {

      const potentialMatches = []

      // Get only words of the correct length
      let filteredWords = words.filter(x => x.length === this.letterCount)

      // Iterate correct letters to map their placement
      this.correctLetters.map((letter, index) => {
        // Return early if undefined
        if (letter === undefined) return;

        // Filter words where indexes match
        potentialMatches.push(...filteredWords.filter(x => x[index] === letter))
      })
      
      return potentialMatches
    }
```

The issue with this approach is that it doesn't take into consideration the indexes of previous letters, it just makes sure that the letter of one particular iteration is at the correct index. What would I want to do to ensure that all indexes match by filtering down as matches are found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that `.every` one of the `.correctLetters` (if the correct letter is defined there) matches at the appropriate index. Don't use `.map` for side effects - since you're trying to create an array by checking which of an existing array matches a condition, use only `.filter`.

```
fetchPotentialWords(){
  return words
    .filter(word => 
      word.length === this.letterCount &&
      this.correctLetters.every((letter, i) => !letter || word[i] === letter)
    );
}
```

Comment: What's the `!letter` check for?

Comment: Good call, thank you. I didn't even think about how easily `every()` could solve this with both conditions, I only tried it with the containment of the letter but not the index. Good work, appreciate it.

Comment: @Phil Some of the `correctLetters` look to be `undefined` and should be ignored.